# Bootstrap - Affix & scrollspy - active on scroll not working

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have the following [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/IlXur)

I can't get the:

- navspy to properly work
- clicking an menu item should also mark it as active
- the last element in the list get's selected with no apparent reason.

I am stuck on this. Anybody willing to enlighten me what I did wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add 'scrollspy' to the body tag in order for it to activate the menu items.

```
<body data-spy="scroll" data-target=".navspy">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/skelly/yPgUu/253/

Comment: I've added 'scrollspy' to a div element. Is that no good? I am not lazy but it's rather difficult to add that to the body (CMS stuff).

Comment: These fiddles don't do anything. Outdated additional resources?

Answer (score 3):

Picking up on the heavy lifting by @Skelly, here's a variation: http://jsfiddle.net/panchroma/TcyBY/

I've moved the scrollspy call out of the body tag to a separate js

```
$('body').scrollspy({ target: '.sidebar-nav' });
```

The documentation on the Bootstrap site for scrollspy could probably be clearer. Here's a link which might help explain some of the blips: http://mtjhax.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/twitter-bootstraps-scrollspy-plugin-needs-better-docs/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the link. I like the title :). Looks good with the js. In both of your examples, clicking the an item in the menu, selects the one above and not the one below. Any idea why?

Comment: > clicking the an item in the menu, selects the one above ... are you sure? If I click 'Office & Engineering' (which is <a href="#3">) section3 jumps to the top of the page

Comment: Where it jumps is right. But the selected position in the menu is wrong.

Comment: I just noticed there's a blip in the display when looking at the jsfiddle multi-pane view. Check the results when viewed full-screen: http://fiddle.jshell.net/panchroma/TcyBY/show/  , does that look better?

Comment: It's still buggy on my machine.

Comment: So when you click 'Office & Engineering', the page scrolls to section3, but the Office & Engineering menu link doesn't have white text on a blue background?

Comment: Don't know why sorry, we seem to see different results. You could try reducing the height your window and see if anything changes.

Comment: Indeed, looks like the height plays an important role. Still looks very buggy. Thanks for looking into this. Would you be a gentelman and allow me to accept Shelly's answer?